# How to render desktop icons in Windows XP

Tags: listview, windows-xp, icons, desktop, render

I would like to render Windows XP desktop icons in my app. They must look identical to the original XP desktop icons and properly react on various changes (like changing desktop icon size etc), i.e. to behave the same way as real desktop icons would do.

Is it possible?

A code snipplets would be appreciated.

Thanks.